# Seaborn heatmap xticklabels do not work well with dates

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, heatmap, missing-data

Maybe this is a recurring problem here. Although I queried old questions on the site, I was unable to solve my problem completely. Some old forum topics helped me a lot:

[Show dates on seaborn heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345177/show-dates-on-seaborn-heatmap)

[Seaborn Heatmap with Datetime Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058347/seaborn-heatmap-with-datetime-axes)

[Date axis in heatmap seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925458/date-axis-in-heatmap-seaborn?rq=1)

[Date axis in heatmap seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40925458/date-axis-in-heatmap-seaborn/41258987#41258987)

But after much trying I still could not figure it out.

My problem is this:

I have a dataframe like this (but the original is much more extensive, being the date index from 2004 to 2018 at one hour intervals).

```
        Estreito    Furnas  Manso   Itumbiara   Curuai
2004-01-19 15:00:00 NaN NaN 3.73    NaN NaN
2004-01-19 16:00:00 NaN NaN 5.10    NaN NaN
2004-01-19 17:00:00 NaN NaN 5.10    NaN NaN
2004-01-19 18:00:00 NaN NaN NaN     NaN NaN
2004-01-19 19:00:00 NaN NaN 4.31    NaN NaN
2004-01-19 20:00:00 NaN NaN 4.90    NaN NaN
2004-01-19 21:00:00 NaN NaN 5.88    NaN NaN
2004-01-19 22:00:00 NaN NaN 7.06    NaN NaN
2004-01-19 23:00:00 NaN NaN 4.71    NaN NaN
2004-01-20 00:00:00 NaN NaN NaN     NaN NaN
2004-01-20 01:00:00 NaN NaN 7.25    NaN NaN
2004-01-20 02:00:00 NaN NaN 5.10    NaN NaN
2004-01-20 03:00:00 NaN NaN 2.55    NaN NaN
2004-01-20 04:00:00 NaN NaN 0.39    NaN NaN
2004-01-20 05:00:00 NaN NaN 0.20    NaN NaN
```

I'd like to show the missing data in a graph, so I'm using the heatmap of the seaborn module.

Following the documentation and old forum topics I get in the following script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df_transposed = df.transpose()

plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(12,6))

ax = sns.heatmap(df_transposed.isnull(), cbar=False)

x_dates = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m').sort_values().unique()

ax.set_xticklabels(labels=x_dates, rotation=45)
```

I got the following figure:

[image]

But as you can see, the xticklabels are not very good. And reading Seaborn's documentation I could not find any arguments to set the number of xticks.

I tried putting only years on xticklabels doing this:

```
x_dates = df.index.strftime('%Y').sort_values().unique()
```

But it doesn't work as well:

[image]

I humbly ask for help to solve this problem. I apologize if I am off topic.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45349235/4124317) that you found already yourself?

Comment: Yep. The answer from 'ImportanceOfBeingErnest' should solve your problem

Comment: In fact, the solution proposed using imshow worked. But I would like to know if it is possible to solve the problem with the seanborn heatmap.